# Update table with multiple conditions psql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

So I have been trying to change the value of my update column to d when user column value is equal to my id variable and when the update column value does not equal null. I tried this but I got a syntax error

```
doc.query("UPDATE request SET update = 'd' WHERE (user = '"+id+"') AND (update != "null")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
doc.query("UPDATE 
                request r 
             SET 
                r.update = 'd' 
             WHERE r.user = '"+id+"' 
             AND r.update IS NOT NULL");
```

If your id is int try this

```
doc.query("UPDATE 
                    request r 
                 SET 
                    r.update = 'd' 
                 WHERE r.user = "+id+" 
                 AND r.update IS NOT NULL");
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change !="null" to update IS NOT NULL.. if you want the update = "null" then try to use update IS NULL..